# A generic one-to-one relation in Django

Tags: python, django, generics, django-models, django-forms

I have an image model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I also have a model which has fields

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField()
    icon = models.ImageField()
    images = generic.GenericRelation(Image)
```

I want `logo` and `icon` to also use the generic relation `Image`. How can I do this?

I use the generic model `Image` in many models so it has to be a generic relation. I just want to use the same model for all images even though it's icons, profile pictures or whatever.

The best would be if Django had a field `generic.GenericOneToOneRelation(Image)` or something :-)

The only solution I can think of is

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    logo = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    images = generic.GenericRelation(Image)
```

and then selecting `logo` and `icon` after uploading `images` and excluding `logo` and `icon` from `images` when I'm printing the `images` related to this model. Would this be a good solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic one-to-one relation in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837330/generic-one-to-one-relation-in-django)